# how do the conversion shown in the example

Tags: c#

definitions

```
Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
Button button3 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
Button buttonOK = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonOK);

button1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
button2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
button3.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

button1.Text = ProductName[0].ToString();
button2.Text = ProductName[1].ToString();
button3.Text = ProductName[2].ToString();
```

I want to use the following

```
for (int i; i < length; i++)
{
    button[i].Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    button[i].Text = ProductName[0].ToString();
}
```

How can I Accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Define array of buttons:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[4];
buttons[0] = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
buttons[1] = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
buttons[2] = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
buttons[3] = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonOK);
```

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: Please mark this as an anwer if it helped you to resolve your issue